# Naming and Extracting shapefiles using value from attribute table using ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, layer-name

I am working with ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro to create a process that will select a distinct shapefile from a feature class and create a new layer. This new layer will then be used to clip and extract by mask a land cover raster.

For organizing purposes I would prefer the new unique shapefiles to be named with a value from their attribute table, this value is "LandCode_ID".

Is there a way to automate the naming process in ModelBuilder so that it pulls the value in the "LandCode_ID" field and then uses that to names the extracted layer or is turning the model into Python and adding a line of code my most viable option?

Comment: Are you iterating over your shapefile by say the FID field or the actual landcode_id field?

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/exporting-a-model-to-python.htm

Comment: I'm using the landcode_ID field. The agency doesn't use the FID to reference the shapefiles.
I believe the "Derived Outputs" section of the url that Yogesh Chavan linked has the answer that I need.